# Datanucleus creates subquery instead of join

Tags: java, orm, datanucleus

I have these annotations:

```
public class Account {
@Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true", dependent = "false")
@Column(name = "user_owner_id")
private User user;
} 

public class User {
@Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true", mappedBy = "user")
@Element(column = "user_owner_id", dependent = "true")
private Set<Account>      accounts;
}
```

When initiating the Account class, the query on the database use a `SELECT * FROM accounts where exists (SELECT id from users where id=23)`

I am trying to give datanucleus an annotation that tells it to run on the database `SELECT a.* FROM accounts a JOIN users u on a.id = u.user_id where  u.id = 23` as this is more optimal.

So which annotation should I use to make data nucleus change its query formation?

--- addition ----

This is a stripped down version of how we're retrieving the data:

```
PersistenceManager persistenceManager = persistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManager();
      persistenceManager.getFetchPlan().setMaxFetchDepth(FetchPlan.FETCH_SIZE_GREEDY);

Query query = persistenceManager.newQuery("javax.jdo.query.JDOQL", null);

query.setClass(User.class);
query.setFilter("this.uuid==p1");
query.declareParameters("java.lang.String p1");

final List<E> entities = (List<E>) query.execute(uuid);

E entity = entities.iterator().next();

return persistenceManager.detachCopy(entity);
```

Comment: what does "initiating the Account class" mean?

Comment: Same as 'retrieve the object'

Comment: great, and care to share HOW you "retrieve the object" ? getObjectById, query? some other way? and when answering that, state which object, by providing actual code

Comment: Well, I'm going to say getObjectById from what I have seen, but the rest, I have an issue providing as I am the DBA and not the developer.

Comment: I am aware that datanucleus is what creates the database tables and manages additions. They use annotations in classes for that.

Comment: Why not get the developer to provide the actual code he uses then people can attempt to explain why it does what it does and what options there are? Annotations are there to define HOW data is put into the database in general, NOT how it is retrieved

Comment: Please find additions to the original question regarding your comments.

Comment: Using a query to get a specific object is an anti-pattern, in general. Pulls in way more resources than if just doing it the normal JDO API route

Comment: I would stay that - from a database point of view - if this was handled in the DB using a JOIN instead of EXISTS (SELECT * FROM..), this would have been MUCH less of a performance issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are performing a `Query` just to get one object, which is very inefficient. Instead you could easily do

```
User u = pm.getObjectById(User.class, 1);
```

and this would likely issues 2 SQLs in total; 1 to get the basic User object, and 1 to get the Accounts connected to that User. There would be no EXISTS clause.

With regards to what you are actually doing. A Query is issued. A Query is general and in most use-cases will return multiple objects. The filter clause of the query can be complex. The Query is converted into an SQL to get the basic User fields. It can't get the related objects in a single call, so your log will likely say something about *BULK FETCH* (or something similar, whatever DataNucleus calls it). This will have an `EXISTS` clause with the `EXISTS` subquery restricting the second query to the objects the Query applies to). They do this to avoid the N+1 problem. Using `EXISTS` is, in general, the most appropriate for the general case of a query. In your specific situation it would have been nice to have an `INNER JOIN`, but I don't think that is supported as a *BULK FETCH* option currently. Their code is open source and I know they have asked people to contribute things in the past where they want alternative handling ... so you could contribute something if you want to use a query in this precise situation.

Comment: Thank you, Neil. This has helped a lot.